# Transferring Lyx Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: lyx, keyboard

I recently updated my version of Lyx from 1.6.7 to 2.0.6. I would like to transfer my old keyboard shortcuts to this new version, but I am having difficulty because I was inconsistent with the way that I set them up:

Some were defined in the specified .bind file, 
but others were modified in the lyx preferences menu.

I found that when importing my old .bind file into this updated version of lyx, it imported the keyboard shortcuts that were in the .bind file, but not those that I had added in the preferences menu.

Does anyone know if these keyboard shortcuts that were added via the preferences menu are stored in another .bind file somewhere in the lyx directory? Has anyone else successfully transferred keyboard shortcuts that had been implimented in the preferences menu?

Answer (score 5):

On my system a `.bind` file was created in the user folder of LyX. You can find out where this folder is located by choosing Help --> About LyX, where the path to the *User directory* is given.

Here (in Kubuntu) the folder is located in `~/.lyx`, and there is a file called `user.bind` in `~/.lyx/bind/`.

Comment: I have a similar problem: I'd like to transfer my shortcuts from one computer to an other, both using Mac OS 10.10. The directory Lyx gives me on the menu "About Lyx" (/Library/Application Support/LyX-2.1/) does not even exist ... I'm using LyX 2.1.2.2, the last update on both Mac's computers. Thanks in advance for any help. I also tried to copy/paste all the .bind files and to reconfigure, the second Lyx does not take into account my personal shortcuts...

Comment: Sorry, I made the comment too fast, I found the correct files to transfer (they were obviously in my user sub-folder, not in the general one, so ~/Library/Application Support/LyX-2.1/ with the ~ !) I copy everything there from one computer to the other, and everything is fine :-) Sorry for the disturbance !

Comment: @FraSchelle I have the same problem and also running on Mac. I found this `user.bind` file. what should I do with it?

Comment: @roi.holtzman Copy-paste it in your other computer at the same place.

Comment: It was found in `~/Library/Application Support/Lyx-2.3/bind` on macOS 12.1