# File location containing the shortcuts of LyX

Tags: lyx, debugging

Is there an editable file that contains all the shortcut a user introduces to LyX (additionally to the standart shortcuts) ?

I already looked in cua.bind and my shortcuts aren't there.

This whole issue arised because I assigned some commands with some weird character-shortcut key (do to the fact that the shift key was involved in creating the shortcut-key) and now I have the problem, that I can't remove them anymore, i.e.if I do, they disappear from the list, but appear again displaying the shortcut list. Restarting LyX didn'help.
I assume this is a bug!

Comment: There is a `bind` file in the LyX user directory, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144246/transferring-lyx-keyboard-shortcuts/144247#144247

Comment: Can you open a new bug report for this *with exact steps to reproduce* at http://www.lyx.org/trac ?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, that worked - should have posted it as an answer!

Comment: @scottkosty Ok, I did it.

Comment: the bug report is here: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8941

Comment: @user10324 excellent instructions to reproduce! I wasn't going to look into fixing this but now that you took the time to be so precise I would like to show my appreciation by taking a deeper look.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @scottkosty I could, unless you think it shouldn't be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't have a preference. I don't think I have enough points to vote for duplicates yet but that would make sense also.