# Reusing custom Lyx .bind file on Linux

Tags: lyx, keyboard

I have been using a custom .bind file for keyboard shortcuts with Lyx 2.1 on Windows. I recently installed Lyx 2.1.4 on Ubuntu and I would like to reuse this .bind file. I placed this file at /usr/share/lyx/bind/custom.bind. Upon selecting this .bind file for keyboard shortcuts, I receive the error message:

> Unable to find the bind file /usr/share/lyx/bind/custom.bind. Please check your installation.

I have also tried placing my .bind file at ~/.lyx/bind, but I still receive the same error message when attempting to select the .bind file. Any ideas on how to get Lyx to import these pre-existing shortcuts?

Comment: I think somebody else had almost this exact same problem.  See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144246/90087 and the comments.

Comment: Yes, A Feldman is right---call the file `user.bind` and put it in `~/.lyx/bind/`.

Comment: Problem solved - I needed to run the program as root in order to change the keyboard bindings by opening lyx with `gksudo lyx`. Then lyx was able to open the custom.bind file.