# How to remap Lyx modifier keys

Tags: lyx

I'm a long time Mac who needs to move to a Windows machine. It looks like I can reuse my Lyx keybindings file, but all the Mac (Command/Ctrl) keys get mapped to Windows (Ctrl/Alt) keys, i.e., precisely reversed physical keys on the same keyboard. Is there a setting within Lyx to swap Ctrl and Alt keys? For example, maybe there is a way to define a custom .kmap under `Settings -> Editing -> Keyboard/Mouse -> Use keyboard map`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the key bindings file is text file there's a trivial workaround, do search/replace in the file.

Comment: Okay it's in plain text. (close LyX before modifying the file)  -- Related: for the location of the file see [keyboard - Reusing custom Lyx .bind file on Linux - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308997/reusing-custom-lyx-bind-file-on-linux) // [Transferring Lyx Keyboard Shortcuts - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144246/transferring-lyx-keyboard-shortcuts) although you already figured that out.

Comment: Thanks, this will be a good workaround if there's not a more general way to control the modifier keys..

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not so simple as it seems. I was previously using `mac.bind` with some customizations, and that additionally depends on more bind files (math.bind, menu.bind, ...). Apparently I would need to modify all these bind files. But it looks like custom bind files cannot depend on other custom files?

Comment: Some interesting history is here: https://wiki.lyx.org/Mac/LyXmodifierKeys . On Mac, there _is_ an option to swap (or not) these keys. Unfortunately, the option does not seem available on Windows. It seems to be a QT limitation.

Comment: I bit the bullet and merged all the .bind files (mac.bind, math.bind, my customizations) into one giant user.bind, and it seems to work great!