# Ctrl+s inserts an omega sign instead of saving the document, escape inserts a sun sign

Tags: lyx

I edited the Lyx bind file [as explained here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144246/transferring-lyx-keyboard-shortcuts) to add a few shortcuts. And since the last restart I have a problem where ctrl+s inserts an omega symbol instead of saving the document, escape inserts a sun symbol instead of escaping from a menu or window. Screen shot:
[image]

My bind file only contains the following lines:

```
Format 2

\bind "C-M-c" "citation-insert"
\bind "C-k" "href-insert"
```

How can I bring back ctrl+s and ctrl+z to their normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by restoring the default Lyx bind file as explained in [this forum post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21551):

> 1. Open LyX and go to About LyX. Write down your User directory (this should be copyable in the next version).
> 2. Exit LyX
> 3. Navigate to where your User directory is and delete it (actully, just move it so that you can restore it if necessary).
> 4. Restart LyX